# How to fetch a particular row from a data set and insert back into a another empty dataset

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, dataset, datarow

I have 2 datasets. I want to fetch a row from first dataset and insert it into another dataset.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try _anything_ so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Answer (score 0):

I have Created Two DataSet with name **ds1** and **ds2**.
Than i have created **4 columns** and **3 ROWS** and added to ds1.

Now In ds2
I have created again **4 columns** with same column names in ds2.

Now we have to add row from ds1 to ds2.
So for example that i have copied row (with index 2) from ds1 and adding to ds2.

Thanking you and ask if you have any further query.

```
    DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();

    // Adding new 4 column to ds1
    ds1.Tables.Add(new DataTable());
    ds1.Tables[0].Columns.Add("column_1", typeof(string));
    ds1.Tables[0].Columns.Add("column_2", typeof(string));
    ds1.Tables[0].Columns.Add("column_3", typeof(string));
    ds1.Tables[0].Columns.Add("column_4", typeof(string));

    DataRow row_1 = ds1.Tables[0].NewRow();
    row_1["column_1"] = "row1cell1";
    row_1["column_2"] = "row1cell2";
    row_1["column_3"] = "row1cell3";
    row_1["column_4"] = "row1cell4";
    ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row_1);

    DataRow row_2 = ds1.Tables[0].NewRow();
    row_2["column_1"] = "row2cell1";
    row_2["column_2"] = "row2cell2";
    row_2["column_3"] = "row2cell3";
    row_2["column_4"] = "row2cell4";
    ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row_2);

    DataRow row_3 = ds1.Tables[0].NewRow();
    row_3["column_1"] = "row3cell1";
    row_3["column_2"] = "row3cell2";
    row_3["column_3"] = "row3cell3";
    row_3["column_4"] = "row3cell4";
    ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row_3);

    GridView1.DataSource = ds1;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();

    ds2.Tables.Add(new DataTable());
    ds2.Tables[0].Columns.Add("column_1", typeof(string));
    ds2.Tables[0].Columns.Add("column_2", typeof(string));
    ds2.Tables[0].Columns.Add("column_3", typeof(string));
    ds2.Tables[0].Columns.Add("column_4", typeof(string));

    DataRow ds2row_1 = ds2.Tables[0].NewRow();
    ds2row_1["column_1"] = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[2]["column_1"].ToString();
    ds2row_1["column_2"] = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[2]["column_2"].ToString();
    ds2row_1["column_3"] = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[2]["column_3"].ToString();
    ds2row_1["column_4"] = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[2]["column_4"].ToString();
    ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Add(ds2row_1);

    GridView2.DataSource = ds2;
    GridView2.DataBind();
```